# Get User Location Coordinates inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath (for TableView Cell tap)

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, location, cllocationmanager

Here's the code - it speaks for itself (see, specifically, the @todo in the code):

```
// Handle taps of certain table rows
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Set up start location
    CLLocationCoordinate2D start;

    // Initialize the location manager, to get user location
    locationController = [[JJGCLController alloc] init];
    locationController.delegate = self;
    [locationController.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    // @todo - Get the latitude/longitude values back from my controller, and
    // set them as the start coordinates.
    //start.latitude = location.coordinate.latitude;
    //start.longitude = location.coordinate.latitude;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D destination;
    destination.latitude = (CLLocationDegrees)[pLatitude doubleValue];
    destination.longitude = (CLLocationDegrees)[pLongitude doubleValue];

    NSString *googleMapsURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/?saddr=%1.6f,%1.6f&daddr=%1.6f,%1.6f",
                                     start.latitude, start.longitude, destination.latitude, destination.longitude];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:googleMapsURLString]];
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to set up a location manager/controller to get the user's location so I can set up a link that will open in the Maps app with a route from the user's location to the destination (lat/lon from pLatitude and pLongitude, respectively).

I've followed the Hello There: A Core Location Tutorial to add my own location controller class (JJGCLController), and in my view controller's `- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location` method, I can see the location, but I can't get the coordinates inside my Table View's `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.

Basically, my app shows an address in each table cell, and when the user taps on the address, I want the Maps app to load, and then a route from the current user location to the address to appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There needs to be at least a small amount of time between calling `-startUpdatingLocation` and having access to the location data.

There are two ways to achieve this - you can either call `startUpdatingLocation` much earlier (for example, when the app starts, or when this particular view appears), or you can delay sending the user to the maps application until after `locationUpdate:` is called, which may happen after an unpredictable amount of time. Neither way is ideal.

Comment: I agree. You need time to get the location.

Comment: Is it essential to send the user over to Maps.app? Would it be feasible to use an MKMapView in your application?

Comment: @Mark - I already have a MapView in my app for locating certain places on a map, but I don't particularly want to add in anything to deal with routes and navigation, so I'm much happier kicking users to Maps.

Also, @grahamparks - I've decided to start the location manager in viewDidLoad, then store the coordinates for later. Not ideal, but it's working. I just wish I could have my cake, and eat it, too.